# How to sub with matched groups and variables in Python

Tags: python, regex

new to python.  This is probably simple but I haven't found an answer.

```
rndStr = "20101215"
rndStr2 = "20101216"
str = "Looking at dates between 20110316 and 20110317"
outstr = re.sub("(.+)([0-9]{8})(.+)([0-9]{8})",r'\1'+rndStr+r'\2'+rndStr2,str)
```

The output I'm looking for is:

```
Looking at dates between 20101215 and 20101216
```

But instead I get:

```
P101215101216
```

The values of the two rndStr's doesn't really matter.  Assume its random or taken from user input (I put static vals here to keep it simple).  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your backreferences are ambiguous.  Your replacement string becomes

```
\120101215\220101216
```

which is two rather large numbers to be backreferencing :)

To solve it, use this syntax:

```
r'\g<1>'+rndStr+r'\g<2>'+rndStr2
```

You also have too many sets of parentheses (or "brackets" if you speak British English like me:) - you don't need parentheses around the `[0-9]{8}` parts which you're not backreferencing:

```
re.sub("(.+)[0-9]{8}(.+)[0-9]{8}",...
```

should be sufficient.

(And, as noted elsewhere, don't use `str` as a variable name.  Unless you want to spend ages debugging why `str.replace()` doesn't work anymore. Not that I ever did that once... noooo. :)

so the whole thing becomes:

```
import re
rndStr = "20101215"
rndStr2 = "20101216"
s = "Looking at dates between 20110316 and 20110317"
outstr = re.sub("(.+)[0-9]{8}(.+)[0-9]{8}", r'\g<1>'+rndStr+r'\g<2>'+rndStr2, s) 
print outstr
```

Producing:

```
Looking at dates between 20101215 and 20101216
```

Answer (score 3):

Notice if you change the value of `rndStr` or `rndStr2` to text (like 'abc') rather than digits, you get something closer to the expected result?

In your expression to `re.sub` you have `r'\1'+rndStr+...` This combines into `'\1'+'20101215'` which then tries to reference the back reference of `\120101215` which is probably not what you intended...

You can use named back references to make the back reference unambiguous:

```
rep1 = "20101215"
rep2 = "20101216"
st = "Looking at dates between 20110316 and 20110317"

print re.sub(r'(?P<fp>.+)[0-9]{8}(?P<lp>.+)[0-9]{8}',
            r'\g<fp>'+rep1+r'\g<lp>'+rep2,st)
```

Better still, use an easier to understand syntax and check the return of the attempted match:

```
m=re.search(r'(?P<fp>.+)[0-9]{8}(?P<lp>.+)[0-9]{8}',st)
if m:
    print m.group('fp')+rep1+m.group('lp')+rep2  #you could use m.group(1) too
else:
    print "no match..."
```

In either case, your desired string of `Looking at dates between 20101215 and 20101216`
 is produced.

The Python docs on named backreferences:

`(?P<name>...)`

> Similar to regular parentheses, but
>   the substring matched by the group is
>   accessible within the rest of the
>   regular expression via the symbolic
>   group name 'name'. Group names must be
>   valid Python identifiers, and each
>   group name must be defined only once
>   within a regular expression. A
>   symbolic group is also a numbered
>   group, just as if the group were not
>   named. So the group named `'id'` in the
>   example below can also be referenced
>   as the numbered group 1.
>
> For example, if the pattern is
>   `(?P<id>[a-zA-Z_]\w*)`, the group can be
>   referenced by its name in arguments to
>   methods of match objects, such as
>   `m.group('id')` or `m.end('id')`, and also
>   by name in the regular expression
>   itself (using `(?P=id)`) and replacement
>   text given to `.sub()` (using `\g<id>`).

Comment: @Syed H: All things being equal, your should pick the first right answer IMHO and that is what you did. I added my answer just as an alternative... Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score -1):

```
rndStr = "20101215"
rndStr2 = "20101216"
mys = "Looking at dates between {0} and {1}".format(rndStr, rndStr2)
```

Please do not use `str` as a variable name; it overwrites the built-in `str` type.

Comment: I don't think OP asks for this.

Comment: The original string has two (different) dates, so this wont work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

```
rndStr = "20101215"
rndStr2 = "20101216"

print "Looking at dates between %s and %s" %(rndStr,rndStr2)
```

Comment: Same here, the original string has two (different) dates, so this wont work. Thanks anyway.